# Can't create an object from one .py file in another .py file in the same directory

Tags: python, class, object, global, nameerror

In one file I create a class called Player, but when I try to create an object of that class in another file I'm told that global name "Player" is not defined. Why would this be?

Edit: At the top of the second file, I say "from player import *" and the Player class is stored in player.py

Comment: Please show the code that caused the error.  Perhaps you have simply not imported the module with the `import` statement?

Comment: Are you properly `import`ing the file with `class Player` in the second file?

Comment: OK, you have an import statement.  Please show us the code (preferably a minimal self-contained example that demonstrates the problem), and show us the complete error message.